# Adjusting spacing in Nav Bar with Centered Logo

Tags: html, css, positioning, nav, spacing

Here I have a nav bar set up with a centered logo. The only problem is that I can't get it to look quite right with spacing. The logo is set to 'position: absolute' 'left: 50%' and 'margin-left: -125px' so that is always in the center. Now I just need to get the text balanced around it in a more symmetrical way, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so.

Here's the HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="navright"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="navright"><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
                <li id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="Images/pantry logo.png" width="536" height="348"/></a></li>
                <li class="navleft"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li class="navleft"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>        
       </div>
  </div><!--end header-->
```

And the CSS.

```
.header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

div ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 105px 70px 40px 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #4f4d4b;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

div ul li a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4f4d4b;
}

.nav ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4f4d4b;
}


#logo a img {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#logo {
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

You can go to the site [here.](http://thomashall.idesignclass.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do, and this is just the way I would normally go about things.

I would take the padding of the li, then add the 105px padding to the top of the header (or nav). Next, add some arbitrary margin-right to each li element (say 48px), while of course setting li:last-child to margin: 0; Next take the padding-top and the height off the li#logo and change it to this:

```
#logo { width: 250px; position: relative; }
```

Finally, just use a transform to center the logo if you are going to use absolute positioning. This essentially does the same thing as the margin-left, but it is a little more flexible. So the image css should look like this:

```
#logo a img {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

I used this code and it worked perfectly for me. I can make you a fiddle or something also if you are having trouble still.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I definitely like the way that is set up more, but I'm still not getting the nav items to be more equally centered around the logo. This is what I am seeing >> http://tinypic.com/r/315fpnb/8     It's mainly the space to the right of "MENU" that is bothering me

Comment: One second, let me see why it's not giving you what it gave me.

Comment: Take all of the padding off of the li. It should be:
nav.nav ul li { margin-right: 70px; }
nav.nav ul li:last-child { margin: 0; }

Comment: Of course. The padding was throwing it off since padding is internal to the element, therefore it was being subsumed into the absolute positioning of the image, whereas margin doesn't have that same problem being external to the element. Also, marking it my answer correct would be awesome :).

Comment: Haha, sorry. A little new to the site. It's been marked now! Also, if its not too much trouble I'm not sure why the nav div is slightly off center, like closer to the left side of the page. I have its margin set to 'margin: 0 auto;'

Comment: Yeah, no problem. It's because that your last li element still has a margin-right. You're going to have to do this, nav.nav ul li:last-child { margin: 0; }, like I said above in order to get rid of that offset. That will just remove the right margin from that last element so that things will even out.